# How to login user to spring-security app using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, vue.js, vuejs2

Hi it's my first post on stack overflow. I want to separate back-end from front-end and create REST API using my Spring Boot app. I use spring-security to login. It use something called JSESSION_ID but how to login and authorize users using Vue.js? I want to make form for login to my service and authorize request with JSESSION_ID.

It's my first app in Vue.js. I try to use code from tutorials and docs but it didn't solve my problem. I also have issues with CORS.

```
    export default {
        name: 'Login',
        data(){
            return{
                username: '',
                password: '',
                error: false
            }
        },
        updated(){
            if (localStorage.token){
                this.$router.replace(this.$route.query.redirect  || '/')
            }
        },
        methods:{
            login(){
                this.$http.post('http://localhost:8080/login', { username: this.username, password: this.password })
                    .then(request => this.loginSuccessful(request))
                    .catch(() => this.loginFailed())
            },
            loginSuccessful (req) {
                if (!req.data.token) {
                    this.loginFailed();
                    return
                }
                this.error = false;
                localStorage.token = req.data.token;
                this.$router.replace(this.$route.query.redirect || '/')
            },
            loginFailed () {
                this.error = 'Login failed!';
                delete localStorage.token
            }
        }
    }
```

I expect to login and authorize users from Vue.js using REST Spring-Boot API.

Comment: what is your authentication provider?

Comment: It's default AuthenticationProvider from org.springframework.security.authentication

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to pass the object `{ username: this.username, password: this.password }` as the data to the request, but you do not specify the Content-Type, which probably defaults to 'text/html' or 'application/json'. You could try to first convert that into form data and then pass it to the request, here is an example with AXIOS:

```
login() {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.set("username", this.username);
  formData.set("password", this.password);
  AXIOS.post('/login', formData, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
      .then((result) => {
        this.loginSuccessful(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.loginFailed();
      })
}
```

Perhaps it would also work without specifying the header, like `AXIOS.post('/login', formData, null)`, haven't tried it.